# How to create a string with loop in python and save it in file

Tags: python, string

I would like to create a string:

```
"FILE1 blabla2\nFILE2 blabla4 ..."
```

and save it in a file. Please note that, in each line of the file the second integer is the double of the first. At the end it should look like:

```
FILE1 blabla2
FILE2 blabla4
...
```

but because I have a big amount of lines of this pattern, it is inefficient to do it manually. I would like to use python for this purpose. I can imagine it could be probably done somehow with:

```
join()
```

but I don't know exactly how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an upper limit for the numbers, you can do something like.

```
>>> "\n".join(["FILE{} blabla{}".format(x, x*2) for x in xrange(1, 10)])
'FILE1 blabla2\nFILE2 blabla4\nFILE3 blabla6\nFILE4 blabla8\nFILE5 blabla10\nFILE6 blabla12\nFILE7 blabla14\nFILE8 blabla16\nFILE9 blabla18'
```

and then just write these to a file using.

```
with open('random.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(["FILE{} blabla{}".format(x, x*2) for x in xrange(10)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_strings = [] 
for i in range(3):
    list_of_strings.append("FILE{0} blabla{1}".format(i, i*2))  # or whatever you need

'\n'.join(list_of_strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n_lines = 2 # Actual number of lines you want

output = "\n".join(["FILE{} blabla{}".format(x, x*2) for x in xrange(1, n_lines+1)])

file = open("your_output_file", "w")

for line in output.split("\n"):
    file.write("{}\n".format(line))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either do that in (almost) one statement:

```
with open("blabla.txt", "w") as bla:
    bla.write("\n".join("FILE%d blabla%d" % (i, i*2) for i in range(1, 5)))
```

or you can prepare your list of `blabla` if you need to reuse it later on:

```
blabla = ["FILE%d blabla%d" % (i, i*2) for i in range(1, 5)] 
with open("blabla.txt", "w") as bla:
    for item in blabla:
        print >> bla, item # Note that this syntax add the new line without using "\n".join
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you hints from which you can figure out very easily:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files